# Reduce duplication between two projects

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, webpack

For example: I have two projects which use many of the same components.
How to reduce duplication between it? How to make them is shared? Maybe, it's making with help webpack?

Comment: In the golden days we would use source control to share code into a project. Currently, in my .NET server side I use NuGet packaging. I package components then install them into projects for reuse. I would assume you would want to do the same thing here, but with npm. So, package your components as node modules, then install into each project. Unfortunately, I don't think this is a straight forward process.

Comment: if it's related to logics or shared functionality  than add a separate class library project and compile it and use compiled dll for each project that way you can reduce duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do this is to extract components that you want to reuse into npm packages. This way, all you need to start using these components is to add them as a dependency in you `package.json` file